# Is there any options to use SQL Server tables in postgresql?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I want to see and query data from SQL Server tables in postgresql. How can I do it? I'm using SQL Server 2014, POSTGRESQL 9.4. Windows 10

Comment: What would be the point of doing this since the SQL Server and Postgres tables won't be able to interact (e.g. via joins)?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: in theory this **is** possible with foreign data wrappers: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrapper  but I don't think there is a FDW for SQL Server that works on Windows

Comment: There are also 3rd party tools like Periscope which allow cross-technology joining between engines like PG and MSSQL (for a cost obviously), although without knowing what [Egor Erokhin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7276251/egor-erokhin) is actually trying to achieve, it's hard to know if that's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There is foreign data wrapper for MS SQL (and Sybase together) - http://pgxn.org/dist/tds_fdw/ (here is github repo - https://github.com/tds-fdw/tds_fdw). But AFAIK from using FDW to other data engines (I use daily MySQL FDW and Elasticsearch FDW + several others erratically) there are always some limitations so full functionality may not be possible.